# How can I find the fixed points of this differential equation?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is to find the fixed points for the equation:
 $ \ddot x + x  + \alpha x^²=  0 $ (and then sketch the global flow of the equation) (for $\alpha>0$)

I know that for the autonomous equation $\dot x = f(x) $ the fixed points are given by solving that f(x)=0 (these are the critical points), but, how this would be in the case of an equation involving only a derivative of order two.

And, for example, what soul´d be the fixed points for the system:

$\dot a = a-b $

$\dot b = a+b $   ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation is equivalent to a $2\times 2$ system
$$
x_1'=x_2, \\
x_2'=-x_1-ax_1^2.
$$
Critical point, is where the flux vanishes, i.e.,
$$
(x_1,x_2)=(0,0) \quad\text{and}\quad (x_1,x_2)=(0,-1/a).
$$

Comment: OK, thank´s for the anser. Only one more question: The fixed points are that points in which the flow vanishes, and the flow vanishes when (in this case) $x_{1}´ =0=x_{2}´ $ ?

Comment: Yes, that's the standard way to define them.

Comment: Ok, and what should we understand for fixed points at infinity? (for example for these two equations) ?

Comment: At infinity the derivatives also die.

Comment: and how can I see the flow at infinity? (this because we cannot draw it)

Comment: You can't see it in the phase plane because time is a hidden parameter. You can only see it if you plot $$ (t,x(t),x'(t)).$$

Comment: ok, I see, that needs to sketch explicitly the time parameter, thank´s for that

Answer (score 0):

To your first question about fixed points of a second order differential equation, you should translate it into a system of two first order differential equations by defining, e.g. $y=\dot{x}$, and then express $\dot{y}=\ddot{x}$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, and then find the fixed points of that system.

Which brings us to your second question, finding the fixed points of the system. I like to think of a system of DE as a DE for a vector function, i.e. $\dot{\vec{x}}=f(\vec{x})$. So you should solve for $\vec{x}$ such that $f(\vec{x})=\vec{0}$. In the example you've written, this means solving for $a$ and $b$ such that $\dot{a}=\dot{b}=0$.